# Column Space of Square Matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Assume that I have a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with columns $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ that are linearly independent.
Say that I want to find the column space of A.
Isn't it possible for me to find some combination of $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ such that I can come up with $
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0
 \end{array} } \right]$,
$\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0
 \end{array} } \right]$ and
$\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1
 \end{array} } \right]$ and just say that the columns of $A$ span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Is anything stopping me from doing this? What is it that limits column spaces?

Comment: I don't know what "full pivots" means. If the columns are linearly dependent then you won't be able to find the linear combinations you want, and the columns won't span ${\bf R}^3$. If "full pivots" prevents linear dependence, then, yes, the columns span ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: Hint: If you have three linearly independent vectors, the dimension of the space that they span is ... $x$ ? How many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are $x$-dimensional?

Comment: Alright. It just seemed odd to me that absolutely any square matrice with independent columns will be able to span $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I understand.

Comment: The singular of "matrices" is "matrix".

Comment: @LethalDiversion If you consider the case when $n=2$, it might be a little clearer why this works. A column vector describes a line through the origin, and linear dependence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ means that the two vectors generate the same line. As long as you're two column vectors don't generate the same line, you can mark every spot in the plane as a linear combination of the two vectors. We use $x$- and $y$-axes for convenience, not because they're the only ones that work.

Comment: Another idea is that a matrix $A$ with linearly independent columns are invertible, so $\forall\ v \in \mathbb{R}^n, v  = A (A^{-1} v)$, so $v \in Ran(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Column space is, at least according to my understanding, the span of the columns of the associated matrix. If the three rows are linearly independent, then Gauss-Jordan elimination will leave you with an identity matrix if the algorithm is taken through to completion. From here, you can conclude that the span is all of $\mathbb R^3$.

Note that this is only true for linearly **independent** columns. If a column can be expressed as the sum of two other columns, then you have only two columns to work with in the span (for a 3x3 matrix). Since two columns form a plane instead of a 3D space, you would have to pick two columns, it doesn't matter which two (think about why?), and use that as your span.